# Magento 2 multi line discounts

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, promotions

I want to save the discount amount of each applied cart rule in a column. I have created a column in the quote table and I have saved the applied rule names in the field using the `sales_quote_save_before` event.

I want to save the discount amount too. My required format is `Rulename1-1000,Rulename2-2000`

How can I do this?

Comment: does Rulename1-1000 stands for Rulename1 gives a discount of £1000

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy Yes

Comment: there was a bounty for this question?

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy yes